# Style every other level in a multilevel list

Tags: css

Is there a way to style every other level in a multilevel list?

For example, to make the code below

```
<ul>
    <li>Normal
        <ul>
            <li>Italic
                <ul>
                    <li>Normal
                        <ul>
                            <li>Italic
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Normal
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Italic
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

look like

- Normal

  - *Italic*

    - Normal

      - *Italic*

        - Normal

          - *Italic*

without having to specify rules for each level.

Comment: Is that list hard coded in HTML or generated? If generated, you could set up a process which would add the corresponding classes to the LI elements.

Comment: That I know of there is no way to do this without being explicit about the element hierarchy

Comment: @ŠimeVidas The list could be hard-coded or generated. I do not have a hands-on problem that I am working on. I am just wondering how it would be coded. (But as others note, large lists like this would probably be generated.)

Comment: Please, read my answer as well, as I believe it is more elegant than the accepted one.

Comment: @LajosArpad : I cannot seem to find any answer of yours. There are current only two answers to the question: xec's and flem's.

Comment: Yes, in the meantime I have tested my solution and concluded that flem was right, so I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can assume a maximum limit (i.e. never more N deep) and the limit is not excessive, then [@xec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18805466/967315) is a fine option.

If your markup is dynamic (e.g. data driven) then consider applying class names when you generate it:

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu-depth-odd">
    <li>
        <ul class="menu-depth-even">
            <li>
                <ul class="menu-depth-odd">
                    ...
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.menu-depth-odd>li {
    font-style: normal;                
}
ul.menu-depth-even>li {
    font-style: italic;        
}
```

Comment: +1 this probably is the better option, i don't imagine a huge list like this would be manually coded

Comment: @xec. I'd hope not, but I've seen it plenty of times before!

Comment: This seems like the most straightforward way to do it. However, my question was not prompted by a real problem but just me wondering if there was any neat way to code such rules. From the answers, it seems like there is not.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I even did a bit of additional research to see if a "depth selector" exists in CSS3 but it seems not I'm afraid.

Comment: @flem, this solves the problem, but it is a little bit messy. Please read my answer which shows how you can apply a rule to the even or odd elements of a selection.

Comment: @LajosArpad. Why is it "a little bit messy"? Your answer does not solve the problem. Yours works on sequential elements rather then nested elements.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have tested it now. Thanks for teaching me a thing today.

Comment: @LajosArpad My pleasure, that's what it's all about :)

Answer (score 4):

I assume your lists are not of infinite depth, so you could do something like this, although clunky;

```css
ul,
ul ul ul,
ul ul ul ul ul {
    font-style: normal;
}
ul ul,
ul ul ul ul,
ul ul ul ul ul ul {
    font-style: italic;
}
```